I put my unity build into my project folder; how do I clean it
I need to use Unity for a project and I am learning how to use it. While learning I have built several builds directly into the project folder; how do I know what files to remove? Deleting everything that can be rebuilt is completely on the table

Maybe create another build in a dedicated folder, and then you can check what new files were created?

how do I know what files to remove ... for this and in general: USE VERSION CONTROL (like e.g. Git) in order to easily roll-back if things go south! - Then you could use this to remove anything that was newly added. There I also listed the essential folders and which ones can be removed safely

AS @Kokodoko suggests, thats probably the cleanest way, as it really depends on what build output as to what files are made..
